# Is there a way for cmake to automatically extend the system PATH variable to compiled executables?

Tags: cmake

Can cmake configuration files also be used to automatically extend the system PATH variable to include the directory paths to all the installed executable applications and if it is possible (and a standard practice), how can I do this?

This way, as soon as I configure all the CMakeLists.txt files and everything compiles (and hopefully runs) nicely, I can start using the applications, and the path configuration would be packaged together with the build process. I am working with Linux and my code is written in C++, but since cmake is cross-platform, the question extends to other systems as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unaware of any capability in CMake to do this. However, we based what we do [what Cantera does](http://code.google.com/p/cantera/source/browse/cantera18/branches/scons/tools/setup_cantera.in?spec=svn856&r=856). They upgraded to SCONS recently instead of their old build system, but the idea still applies.

Anyway, there's a script that CMake configures with the paths during the configure step and then installs somewhere. So once built on Linux, one would run `make install` then `source ~/setup_cantera` and it sets up all the variables needed.

We do the same thing for our libraries built with CMake. It's possible to detect which shell the user is running and configure an appropriate template script.

Comment: Thanks, I'll prepare a script that sets the variables, and prescribed set of fixed installation rules.. :)

Comment: No problem. It's usually a good idea for your codes/build environments not to "corrupt" or alter the user environment. Besides, even if CMake could change environment variables, it would only be for that login session so you'd have to rebuild just to reset the environment. So the script is the best way to go.